# Coordinate points of a contour

Tags: python, opencv

I need to find edge coordinates of a contour. I tried to figure out by using cv2.boundingRect but not successful as it shows in 2D (i didn't try image warp yet..).I need to know 3D coordinates of a contour.

My code:

```
import cv2
# import numpy as np

while True:

    image = cv2.imread('box_2.jpg')

    img_dimension = image.shape

    print("Original image dimension : ", img_dimension)

    # Convert the image from colour to gray as 1st step to remove colour related noises...
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Blur the image..
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
    # Perform Adaptive Threshold..
    threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)
    # Find Edge..
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 255, 512)
    # Dilate..
    # edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None)
    # Find Contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cv2.b
    max_area = 0
    max_index = -1
    index = -1

    for i in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        index = index + 1
        if area > max_area:
            max_area = area
            max_index = index

    cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
    print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
    print("Area :{}".format(area))

    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, max_index, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Contours', image)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Detected contour:

[image]

Where i can find this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify more, because the contour itself array of coordinates. Do you mean your box corner coordinate?

Comment: The image only provides 2D coordinates. You need a camera model and a model of the object in the image to project 2D to 3D.

Comment: @Vatsal Parsaniya yes the box coordinates.I need those coordinates. How to get that?. On your second hint (about camera model and model of the object) where can i refer this?

Comment: See [OpenCV's docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use convexHull and approxPolyDP to find out these points. Tweak the parameters for approxPolyDP to fine tune.

```
img_h, img_w = img.shape
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(np.copy(img),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > img_h*img_w*0.05:  # filter noise
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)    # convex hull of contour
        hull = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull,0.1*cv2.arcLength(hull,True),True)
        print(cv2.boundingRect(cnt))
        print(hull)
```

Further reading: [OpenCV Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: He wants 3D coordinates, not 2D.

Comment: To me that seems like an incorrectly posed question. He is perhaps looking for corners of the box in 2D (which he is referring to as 3D points?) and not the bounding box.

Comment: Yes, it is poorly written. He needs to explain much better what he wants.

Comment: @fmw42 you might be right after all. R.M.S.Sundaram, if you are looking to find out World coordinates wrt camera, then that's a much more complex problem and you will need to study stereo vision for that. You will have to first estimate your camera's internal parameters and then use stereo vision (with the assistance of image registration) to find out World coordinates. Btw., understanding the math isn't all that hard. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html

Comment: I am from Asia so i believe there might be time difference and delay to reply. It was middle of the night so i can't reply back to you ASAP

Yes i am looking for 3D coordinates for all 6 or 7 edges. From the contour i believe it's already clear that its more than 2D plane. I have stereo camera and i am able to measure depth etc. The reason why i put here is to know is there an easiest way to determine the edges since i need those to measure distances from point A to B and find the volume of a shape. My other method is by using ML. But preparing the dataset is trivial.

Comment: I think the confusion was caused by you mentioning boundingRect to find 3D coordinates, which is only going to give you the enclosing rectangle for the contour. The solution I posted above will give box contour corners in image plane. If you have the depth map then you can combine these two to get 3D coordinates. If you don't have the depth map then here's how you can estimate it https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Comment: Please post the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the three edges by detecting the one coordinate of the corner joining the three edges, as you already have the other six corners.

The way I chose to tackle this is by the concept that the top face of a box is usually brighter than the side faces if the source of light is above the box. With that in mind, we can define a color mask that masks out almost everything except the relatively brighter shade of the box's color.

With the contours of the top face, we can find the corner by extracting the coordinate with the greatest y coordinate.

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function that will take in an image, and return the image with almost every masked out except the top face of the box:

```
def get_masked(img):
    lower = np.array([90, 0, 40])
    upper = np.array([135, 255, 255])
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

3. Define a function that will take in the masked image, and return it processed to remove noise and detected edges:

```
def get_processed(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 1)
    return cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50)
```

4. Define a function that will return the contour of an edge image with the greatest area:

```
def get_contour(img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    return max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

5. Utilize the functions we defined on an image read into the `img` variable:

```
img = cv2.imread('box_2.jpg')
img_masked = get_masked(img)
img_processed = get_processed(img_masked)
```

6. Get the contour from the processed image, use the `np.argmax` method to extract the coordinate with the greatest y coordinate, and draw it onto the original image:

```
cnt = get_contour(img_processed)
corner = cnt[np.argmax(cnt, 0)].squeeze()[1]
cv2.circle(img, tuple(corner), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

7. Finally, show the image:

```
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Altogether:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_masked(img):
    lower = np.array([90, 0, 40])
    upper = np.array([135, 255, 255])
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

def get_processed(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 1)
    return cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50)

def get_contour(img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    return max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

img = cv2.imread('box_2.jpg')
img_masked = get_masked(img)
img_processed = get_processed(img_masked)

cnt = get_contour(img_processed)
corner = cnt[np.argmax(cnt, 0)].squeeze()[1]
cv2.circle(img, tuple(corner), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```